# Solr stats for each group seperately

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am trying get the specified stat for each grouped data in solr. I managed to grouped the data, but the stats are for the whole data not for each group.

```
group=true&group.field=potential_campaign_type&group.ngroups=true&group.limit=0&stats=true&stats.field=potential_total_amount
```

My solr params are like in the above. This returns me the whole stats for data. However, I need the stats for each grouped object. How can I do this?

Comment: You're probably going to have use faceting instead (and possibly facet pivoting) to get statistics for separate groups: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_7/faceting.html#combining-stats-component-with-pivots

Comment: Okay, I will look into it thank you!

Comment: is tagging avaible in v4.1?

Comment: It is, but the combination of stats and pivoting might not be. 4.1 is far too old to be documented on the same level and for me to remember details.

Comment: Thank you, I just found the 4.10 documentation's pdf, and from that I found stats.facet, and it simplt doing what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using solr 4.10 version and from the documentations pdf

[documentation](https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-4.10.pdf)

I found the `stats.facet` key and it worked. My search params are :

```
stats=true&stats.field=potential_total_amount&stats.facet=potential_campaign_type
```

it returns the stats for the grouped data.